# Probability of breaking a covalent bond through collisions

Tags: solid-state-physics, carrier-particles

I was watching a lecture and at some point they say that for a covalent bond of 1.1 eV and for particles with 0.026 eV mean energy, the number of particles requiered to break the bond is 42, that is 1.1/0.026=42. I’m wondering why we need to do this operation

Comment: What exactly are the "shocks" in your title?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that this is the division of the total energy required by the energy per particle. This gives the total number of particles that we need to bring together in one place to reach the total energy required.

The longer answer is that the probability of more than three particles colliding simultaneously at the same bond location is near zero. So, with 42 particles needing to collide at the location of the covalent bond just to break that bond, the chance of breaking the bond with those particle particles is essentially if not practically zero.

An informative companion exercise is to convert the 1.1 eV to an equivalent thermal temperature in K. The equation is $T = E/k$, where $T$ is temperature (K), $E$ is energy (eV), and $k$ is the Boltzmann constant (eV/K). You will find a value on the order of $10^4$ K. This is significantly larger than a “room temperature” thermal value of 25 meV.